# Generalization of Mathematical Induction?

Tags: induction, set-theory

Yesterday one of my friend and I was discussing about the Principle of Mathematical Induction. After some time he made the following,

> **Theorem.** Let $\emptyset \subset X\subseteq Y$ and $f:X\to Y$ be a function such that,
>
> - for all $y\in Y\setminus X$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$.
> - $f(X)\subseteq X$.
>
> Then $X=Y$.
>
> *Sketch of the Proof of the Claim.* If $X=Y$ then we have nothing to prove. Otherwise suppose that $X\subset Y$. Then there exists $y\in Y\setminus X$. But by the first property we can conclude that there exists $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. By the second property we can conclude that $y(=f(x))\in X$, a contradiction. So we are done.

Now the interesting thing is that from the above theorem we can prove the so called Weak Principle of Mathematical Induction by taking $Y=\mathbb{N}$ and $X\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $1\in X$ and by taking $f:X\to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(n)=n+1$ for all $n\in X$.

The above observation suggests that the above theorem is more general than the Principle of Mathematical Induction. But I couldn't find any literature regarding this type of 'induction'. The question is,

> Is this type of 'induction' well known? If so, can some literature regarding this be mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure how what you've said proves weak induction. Sure, if $X$ is such that $1\in X$ and for each $n\in X$, we also have $n+1\in X$, why does $S: X \to \mathbb{N}$ satisfy the first property that for all $m\notin X$ there is $n\in X$ such that $m=n+1$?  The theorem you write is certainly true, but doesn't seem like an induction schema in any way; it effectively is saying that "if $f:X \to Y$ maps into $X$ but also maps onto $Y\setminus X$, then $Y\setminus X$ is empty", and I'm not so sure there's induction going on here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like Hayden pointed out in the comments, your theorem doesn't really have much to do with mathematical induction. Notice that the first hypothesis of your theorem says that $Y\backslash X \subseteq f(X)$. So the two hypotheses of your theorem combined says that 
$$Y\backslash X \subseteq f(X) \subseteq X.$$
Your theorem effectively says that if $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\backslash X\subseteq X$, then $Y=X$. It has nothing to do with $f$ in particular. This is not a statement about induction or even mappings, but rather a statement about set inclusions.

Answer (score 2):

It does not implies induction. One  of your hypotheses is that $f(X)\subseteq X$, and when proceeding by induction you want to prove exactly this for $f(n)=n+1$, so you can deduce $X=\mathbb{N}$.